Running out of memory when building catkin workspace
I'm trying to build my catkin workspace using the "catkin_make" command but I'm always running out of memory. In fact, the error that I get is the following:
Invoking "make -j16 -l16" failed

In my opinion this problem is related to the fact that all my packages (such as realtime_tools, ros_control, control_toolbox, etc.) are all located inside the same catkin workspace.
Is there an other folder where to install all these packages? Thanks in advance
